# Is it correct to think of the Laplacian as the divergence of a gradient field?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, physics, vector-analysis, mathematical-physics

Factoring out the notation, I see that

$$\nabla^2(\phi) = \nabla \cdot \nabla(\phi) = \nabla \cdot (\nabla(\phi)) $$

which looks something like the divergence of the gradient of phi.

Is it actually true?

Thanks,

Comment: this insight provides the basis for Faraday's intuitive approach to envisioning an electric or magnetic vector field satisfying Laplace's equation in terms of "tubes of force"

Comment: Thanks for the interesting background information @DavidHolden -- I look forward to the day when I get to slow down just a bit with mathematics and actually understand more about the physical sense that the mathematics is conveying :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is correct. Indeed, let $\phi \colon \mathbb{R}^N \to \mathbb{R}$ be of class $C^2$, then 
\begin{align}
\operatorname{div}(\nabla\phi) := \sum_{i = 1}^N\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\nabla\phi)_i = \sum_{i = 1}^N\frac{\partial^2 \phi}{\partial x_i^2} =: \Delta\phi.
\end{align}

Comment: Hi Giovanni -- ok got it.  Thanks for your answer.  Can I ask you one follow-up question?  Then the above, in a sort of abuse of notation, is viewed as a "dot-product", $\nabla$ . $\nabla$.  Now, can I actually use the linearity (and conjugate-linearity) properties of the inner product?  For instance, if I now had $\nabla .  (2f_x, 2f_y, 2f_z)$, is this equal to $2 \nabla .  (f_x, f_y, f_z)$ ?  Thanks,

Comment: Hi, yes you can: the divergence is a first order differential operator (linear combination of first order derivatives, roughly speaking) hence you can treat it as you would normally treat any linear transformation. Any time you are not convinced by something you can prove it directly from the definition (the proof won't be longer than my answer above) :)

Comment: Ah, now that you put it that way, of course it is a linear combination of first order derivatives.  Thanks so much for this.  Yea, I am usually ok with proving out properties, using strictly the definitions, but I was thinking that the "dot product" of the two symbols was more abuse of notation (to remember the order and type of computations) than a "true" dot product (specifically, for 3-D Euclidean space).  So I just wanted to confirm.  Thanks so much @Giovanni - have a great day :-)